# How to convert xml to docx?

Tags: xml, meteor, docx

I am working on an application with meteor, and need to replace specific words  in a docx document. I found a way to convert docx files to xml, the replacements I need to make, take place in the xml-file.

The question is, how can I restore docx-document after replacing those words in xml?

Comment: docx is a zipped container containing xml-files and images. Unless you want to get dirty i'd recommend you working using that in mind.

Comment: thank you @EricHerlitz for your answer, in fact i want to convert it so the user of my application can edit and also to make the print easier

Comment: Can I ask you, in which way you convert docx to xml, and specifically, what xml-dialect are you converting to? Microsoft WorprocessingXML (WML: the xml inside the docx-container) can be very complex, and thus it is very hard to create a roundtrip (WML->XML->WML) without information-loss

Comment: I'm using the tools suggested by microsoft office (i guess i'll use document xml word)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That depends heavily on the XML-dialect you are using to represent your data. The docx format itself is just a collection of xml and resource files, packed in a zip-container. If you rename your file from `file.docx` to `file.zip` you can extract it and see it for yourself.

Lets have a quick glance at the folder-structure in the container:

`docx
 |
 + _rels (...)
 + docProps (...)
 + word
 |  + media (...)
 |  + _rels (...)
 |
 |  - document.xml
 |  - footnotes.xml
 |  - styles.xml
 |  - footer(...).xml
 |  - header(...).xml
 - [ContentTypes].xml`

The most important file is the document.xml. Here is the whole text and document-structure stored, as well as references to footnotes (defined in `footnotes.xml`), styles (`style.xml`) and resources (`media`-folder), header/footer-information and everything else.

The XML-dialect used by docx is: [Wordprocessing XML (WML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/cc820745) from Microsoft. This XML-dialect is (from my experience) relativeley complex and hard to format correctly.

If your XML-file is already in WML then hooray, you are almost done. The only thing you have to do is pack your `document.xml` (or other resource files you have edited) back to the zip-container, or create a new container from the extracted and processed one. Don't forget to rename the `.zip` back to `.docx` if you did.

If you have an XML-file in another dialect (e.g. docbook; TEI; DITA), then you will have to write a converter from that dialect to Wordprocessing XML, to create a `document.xml` and other resource-files. And pack it back, as I described above. As far as I know there are no ready-to-use open-source converters of that kind.

Comment: My XML-file is already in WML. I tried what you suggest, but, it doesn't work. Maybe, i didn't understand it well. would you please tell me which container you're talking about ?

Comment: With container I mean the docx-file itself. As said, docx is just a zip-container after all. Extracting the document.xml, edititng it and packing it back to the archive should work... I do it all the time, make sure you put the document-xml back in the right place, the zip is not read-only, and the text you want to edit is really in that xml-file (and not in header[x].xml; or footnotes.xml)

Comment: @Najoua: would be nice of you do accept my answer and give me a point ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can do so by running the command `zip -r new-doc-file-name.docx *` you must be in the folder containing all xml files and required folders.